# The While running Docker container getting error "current working directory, nor any of its parents, seems to be a Nanoc site"

Tags: docker, nanoc

**My docker file**

```
FROM ruby:latest

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY Gemfile .

# Copy the files
COPY . ./docs

RUN bundler install    
RUN bundle exec nanoc

EXPOSE 5300 
CMD [ "nanoc", "view" ]
```

**While Running the build container:**

**Step : 1**

Successfully built 2fa7cc6d083b

**Step : 2**

```
 root@ubuntu:/var/docs# docker run -p 0.0.0.0:4300:4300 --name nanoc-latest -t -d nanoc:latest                                                                                                

414b227902d15bbe831d8c77f7c68a3c2ca48ae20c9f20e68f92d52f55350b31
```

**Step : 3**

```
root@ubuntu:/var/docs# docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED   STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

**Step : 4**

```
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-sgp1-01:/var/docs# docker ps -a
```

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED
                                                                                                                       STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES

```
414b227902d1        nanoc:latest        "/bin/sh -c /usr/loc…"   9 seconds ago    Exited (1) 6 seconds ago  nanoc-latest
```

**Step : 5**

```
root@ubuntu:/var/docs# sudo docker logs 414b227902d1
```

A Gemfile was detected, but Bundler is not loaded. This is probably not what you                                                                                                              want. To run Nanoc with Bundler, use `bundle exec nanoc`.

**Error:The current working directory, nor any of its parents, seems to be a Nano**                                                                                                             c site.

**I tried to open the nanoc image container**

```
root@ubuntu:/var/docs#   docker run -ti --entrypoint=sh nanoc   
# ls  
Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  docs   
# cd docs    
# ls   
Dockerfile  Gemfile  m1  m2  m3  m6
```

So no nanoc file.

Comment: Are you running using dockerfile or just using commands ?

Comment: Yes i am using the Docker file.

Comment: The error message suggests `bundle exec nanoc`; does that help?

Comment: No, same error i am getting even after add the bundler exec nanoc. I need to run the commend inside the nanoc file. We need to find how to move inside the nanoc file and run the bundler nanoc i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker file:

```
FROM ruby:2.3
RUN mkdir -p /user/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/docs

RUN bundle install
RUN bundle exec nanoc
EXPOSE 3000
CMD bundle exec nanoc view
```

Docker build command:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t nanoc:latest .
docker run -p 0.0.0.0:3000:3000 --name nanoc-latest -t -d nanoc:latest
```

Successfully you get the deployed index.html file